# Oracle 10g multiple DELETE statements

Tags: sql, insert, oracle10g, sql-delete

I'm building a dml file that first deletes records that may be in the table, then inserts records.
Example:

```
DELETE from foo where field1='bar';
DELETE from foo where fields1='bazz';

INSERT ALL
 INTO foo(field1, field2) values ('bar', 'x')
 INTO foo(field1, field2) values ('bazz', 'y')
SELECT * from DUAL;
```

When I run the insert statement by itself, it runs fine. When I run the deletes, only the last delete runs.

Also, it seems to be necessary to end the multiple insert with the select, is that so? If so, why is that necessary?
In the past, when using MySQL, I could just list multiple delete and insert statements, all individually ending with a semicolon, and it would run fine.

Comment: One delete is has a condition on field1 and the other on fields1.  That won't work properly.

Comment: did you set auto_commit to true?

Comment: The INSERT ALL requires a query. Don't worry, the SELECT from DUAL is very fast (in fact, a NO-OP in Oracle 11g).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apparently have a typo, since you're calling it either `field1` or `fields1` in the DELETEs.

You're doing it the hard way, though.

```
DELETE FROM Foo WHERE Field1 in ('bar', 'bazz');

INSERT INTO Foo (Field1, Field2) 
  SELECT 'bar', 'x' FROM System.dual UNION 
  SELECT 'bazz', 'y' FROM System.dual;
```

Not sure if Oracle requires the `FROM System.dual`, although I seem to recall it did. SQL Server will allow just a `SELECT 'bar', 'x'` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Any particular reason you don't want to:

```
insert into foo(field1, field2) values('bar', 'x');
insert into foo(field1, field2) values('bazz', 'y');
```